# App crashed when trying to launch an AdMob

Tags: java, android, crash, admob, banner-ads

When ever I try to run the App it won't start, it keeps crashing without giving any error. When I remove("Comment it out") the app works just fine with no problems. Below is all the code... please help

Main:

```
package pres.com.pad;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
//import android.view.Window;
//import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class main extends AppCompatActivity {


private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

 }
}
```

Strings:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Pad</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
</resources>
```

Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
tools:context="pres.com.pad.main"
>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pres.com.pad">

<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pres.com.pad"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I wish there was something from LogCat I could post but LogCat is empty and it is reading the process. All that happens is when I run the app it will load the APK on the VD and a Dialog Box will appear will saying "App Stopped Working"

Comment: Try to update to 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4' and remove 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4' from dependencies.

Comment: @PavelPoley unfortunately it did not work. But now logCat is showing an Error: 05-14 05:19:57.316 2216-2306/com.android.launcher3 W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
Maybe its one small step forward lol

Comment: After more Debugging... the (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView) returns Null. Causing mAdView.loadAd(adRequest) to fail and crash the app

Comment: what is new gamePanel()? why you not set the layout with the adMob banner?

Comment: @PavelPoley GamePanel is a View but I've corrected the issue by adding a RelativeLayout to the main Layout and added the GamePanel View to RealtiveLayout within the main layout. Everything is working great!